# How to use cursor and when to close connection in mysql-connector

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, database, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python

I'm quite new into using databases with python. My question is: I'm creating a class "Database" from the mysql.connector in which I'm implementing some methods inside this class to create tables, delete tables, etc... I want to know if it is right to create a class variable which is the connector(`mysql.connect()`). I mean, can I keep the connection on while the application is open, or should I open and close the connection on each query? The main purpose of this Database class I'm creating is to use as a query mechaninsm in another app.

Another question is: how the cursor works. Should I create and close a cursor for each query, or can I do the way I'm doing: creating a `self.cursor` and calling it on each query I want?

```
import mysql.connector as mysql
from mysql.connector import errorcode


class Database(object):
    def __init__(self, host, user, user_pass, database_name):
        self.host, self.database_name = host, database_name
        self.user, self.user_pass = user, user_pass
        try:
            self.connect = mysql.connect(
                host= host, user= user,
                passwd= user_pass, database= database_name
            )
            print("Successfully connected to database: {}.".format(database_name))
            self.cursor = self.connect.cursor()
            self.tables = self.get_all_tables()

        except mysql.Error as err:
            print(err)


    def create_table(self, table_name, columns):  #<-- expects a string and a list of tuples
        command = ['{} {}'.format(col[0], col[1]) for col in columns]
        command = ', '.join(command)
        try:
            self.cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE {} ({});".format(table_name, command))
            print("Table \"{}\" successfully created.".format(table_name))
        except mysql.Error as err:
            if err.errno == errorcode.ER_TABLE_EXISTS_ERROR:
                print("Table \"{}\" already exists.".format(table_name))
            else:
                print(err)


    def remove_table(self, table_name):
        try:
            self.cursor.execute("DROP TABLE {};".format(table_name))
            print("Table \"{}\" removed.".format(table_name))
        except mysql.Error as err:
            print(err)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #Configuring the database
    DATABASE_NAME = 'company_employees'
    config = {
        'host': 'localhost',
        'user': 'root',
        'pass': 'rootpass123',
        'db': DATABASE_NAME  # <-- Connects to database accounts
        }
    db = Database(config['host'], config['user'],
                  config['pass'], config['db'])
```